# Is it possible to trade multiple assets with one script?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to implement a pairs trading algo in Pine Script but I don't know how to select a specific asset to buy or sell. It seems I'm locked with the current symbol.

Comment: Have a look at the security() function.

Comment: security() function would not help

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not possible in PineScript. Yes, you may get data of a different assets with the security() function, but, it's forbidden to execute strategy.XXX functions in a secondary security context.